# Where can I ask questions regarding apps?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

Let's say I need help with certain apps - like Spotify or Photoshop - with regards to technical issues.

I may ask questions like *How do I view history tab* or *how do I access this tool* and what not. What is the best SE site to ask these types of app-specific questions that require tech support?

Comment: Feels like it might be on-topic on Superuser.com and if it is a web application webapps.se could work. Check their help center before you post there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the device running those apps.

- Desktop computers, laptops: [Super User](https://superuser.com)
- Android device: [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search)
- iOS device: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search), also includes Mac OS so there is an overlap with Super User there.
- Windows Phone: [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Super User](https://superuser.com) is the right place for those type of questions. To quote that site's [Asking](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) page, questions about computer software are on topic there.

Comment: But ... there are a lot of software questions that are **not** on-topic. For example, software recommendations, wordpress questions, web applications, ...

Comment: True, but I don't want people to take "questions about computer software are on topic" the wrong way.